# gtk+ setup RuntimeError: Failed to close xcrun -f gcc stream

Tags: c++, bash, gtk, popen, xcrun

beginner coder here.

I'm trying to set up gtk+ to set up a GUI for a program. I'm following the procedure section of these instructions: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building

I have downloaded the code they provide, but cannot get further than that. I am attaching a screenshot of commands that I ran and the error that I got.

If anyone has any ideas, would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the errors instead of attaching a screenshot, please? The screenshot makes it impossible for others to google the error. (Also, you forgot to attach it.)

Comment: *Hey, thanks for the comment - the screenshot wouldn't upload because I don't have enough StackOverflow points, I ended up bailing on gtk+ as I couldn't get it to load correctly, moved on to Electron. Thanks again!